# QT 5.4 errors after connection DLL

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I'm new here. I would like to ask where the error is.
I made my own `dll` (via codeblocs), and I wanted to use it in another qt project
Everything I set up and perform qmake, but it still throws me `LNK2019` and LNK1120.
I attach a code library and qt project

**dll6.dll

main.h**

```
using namespace std;
#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus

#endif

DLL_EXPORT void SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext);
DLL_EXPORT int text_pozdrav(int i);

#ifdef __cplusplus

#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

**main.cpp**

```
DLL_EXPORT int text_pozdrav(int i)
{
    return i;
}
```

**usingdll3(QT)
usingdll3.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-02-06T13:47:38
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = usingdll3
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS += \../dll6/main.h

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../dll6/bin/Debug/libdll6.a
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../dll6/bin/Debug/libdll6.a
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../dll6/bin/Debug/ -adll6

LIBS += -LC:/Users/Jakub/Documents/Projekty/dll6/bin/Debug/dll6.dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../dll6/bin/Debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../dll6/bin/Debug
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"


using namespace std;
DLL_EXPORT int text_pozdrav(int i);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    cout << text_pozdrav(22) << endl;

    return a.exec();

}
```

**Errors**

```
LNK2019: main.obj:-1: Chyba: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl text_pozdrav(int)" (__imp_?text_pozdrav@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
LNK1120: debug\usingdll3.exe:-1: Chyba: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

thank you for your answers

Comment: `LIBS += -LC:/Users/Jakub/Documents/Projekty/dll6/bin/Debug/dll6.dll` There should be a .lib file (not a .dll), that is generated, when you compile your library.

Comment: I rewrote it, but still the same error. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

resolved, codeblock compiled in gcc and qt in Visual C++